# Cannot drop column needed in a foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, database-connection

Executing SQL script in server

> ERROR: Error 1829: Cannot drop column 'cod_Cliente': needed in a foreign key constraint 'fk_Cuotas_Clientes1' of table 'gimnasio.cuotas'

```
ALTER TABLE `Gimnasio`.`Clientes` DROP COLUMN `Observación` , 
DROP COLUMN `Cedula` , DROP COLUMN `cod_Cliente` , 
CHANGE COLUMN `FechaDeNacimiento` `FechaDeNacimiento` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
CHANGE COLUMN `Dirección` `Dirección` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL  , 
ADD COLUMN `cod_Cliente` INT(11) NOT NULL  FIRST , 
ADD COLUMN `Cédula` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER `Apellido` , 
ADD COLUMN `Observación` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER `Telefono` ,
DROP PRIMARY KEY , 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cod_Cliente`)
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 12 succeeded, 1 failed

Comment: Drop the foreign key constraint before dropping the column?

Comment: Also, please do not tag languages that have nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 4):

**Remove** the foreign key before modifying a primary key field:

```
ALTER TABLE gimnasio.cuotas
  DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_Cuotas_Clientes1
```

After that, **do** your `ALTER TABLE`.

And finally, do not forget to **create** again the relationship:

```
ALTER TABLE gimansio.cuotas ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Cuotas_Clientes1 FOREIGN KEY (col_name) REFERENCES gimnasio.Clientes(cod_Cliente);
```

Comment: I am sorry, but i am new in this

Comment: The first block before your instruction. And the ending block after your instruction. (Replace `col_name` with the column name of your table `cuotas`

Comment: Do not forget to accept this as answer if it solved your problem.